# How to Add Attribute without Edit base Class? C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, attributes, partial

I want to add validation attribute in properties, but I cat't edit class because these properties are created by Entity Framework.
So I created new partial class, for example...

```
/// <summary>
/// Created by Entity Framework, so can't edit class
/// </summary>
public partial class PartialClass
{
    public  string AAA { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Can edit class, so I add "Required" Attribute
/// </summary>
public partial class PartialClass
{
    [Display(Name="Column AAA.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No Value!")]
    public string AAA { get; set; }
}
```

but this code build error.

How to add attribute instead of edit base class??

**※11:06 - edited**
Add DisplayAttribute, And "Required"ErrorMessage.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to touch your entities I suggest you to use [**Fluent Api**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.5) instead **Data Annotations**

If you override the [`OnModelCreating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.103).aspx) method of your context you can specify that property as required:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourClass>().Property(t => t.AAA).IsRequired();
```

Another way could be using the [`EntityTypeConfiguration`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entitytypeconfiguration-class.aspx) class to configure each entity explicitly, for example:

```
public class YourClassMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<YourClass>
{
    public YourClassMap()
    {
        this.Property(t => t.AAA).IsRequired();
        //Here you can specify the PK of your entity, relationships,...
    }
}
```

This way you can use Fluent Api to configure an entity and its properties and override various Code-First conventions.

After you finish to map all your entities, you need to add those configuration classes to your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new YourClassMap());
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```